# Why the "blurred virtual background" option is not available on Zoom in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, zoom-meeting

I have installed the latest version of Zoom (5.7.4 (28991.0726)) on my ubuntu desktop (20.04 LTS). I want to set  "blurred background" as virtual background for my zoom meetings. But this option is not available? In the virtual background setting, I get few different options but not the blurred one. However, I get this option in the Zoom app on my iPad. I don't know why it is not available on my desktop. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

By all accounts it doesn't look as though this option is available on Linux clients but you could ask the Zoom Help Center.

[reference](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360061468611-Using-blurred-background-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was adding in version 5.10, although it still appears to be a little buggy. I'm using the most recent version on Ubuntu, and I see the option to "Blur My Background", but with it enabled, the video doesn't work.

Comment: I can't tell _why_, but background-blurring in Zoom _did not_ work on my NUC8i7. It _did_ work on my newer laptop until Wednesday, April 6, 2022.

Now, selecting that option kills my video too .